# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am getting the following error after deleting my data using Angular.js and PHP.

> Error:

```
angular.min.js:118 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at xc (http://localhost/sunil/assets/js/angular.min.js:16:379)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
$scope.deleteData=function(id){
        $http.post("model/add.php", {
            'id':id,
            'action':'Delete'
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
           console.log('add data',data,JSON.parse(data));
            if(data.msg !=""){
                $rootScope.msg = data.msg;
                $rootScope.alertclass = "alert-success";
                $scope.dataList.splice(id, 1);
            }else{
                $rootScope.msg = data.error;
                $rootScope.alertclass = "alert-danger";
            }
        });
    }

if($data->action == 'Delete'){
        $data_id = $data->id;
       // echo ($data_id);exit;
        $deleteQry = "DELETE FROM ang_user WHERE id='$data_id'";
        $result = $conn->query($deleteQry);
        if ($result) {
            $arr = array('msg' => "Data Deleted Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');
        } else {
            $arr = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error In Deleting record');
        }
    }
    $json = json_encode($arr);
    print_r($json);
```

Data is deleting from database but inside success function its throwing this error. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: `console.log('add data'+data+JSON.parse(data));` instead of `,`

Comment: Clearly, the data you're trying to parse isn't valid JSON. It has a `<` where one isn't expected. We can't help you with it if you don't show the JSON. Your code shows that you're writing it out to the console. Well, what does it look like?

Comment: @Loading..: No, the way the OP's doing it will be more useful. `console.log` outputs each argument individually, in a way most suited to its data type; munging them all together with `+` is likely to hide useful information. But the real thing to do here is use the debugger.

Comment: @Loading.. : I did as per you but same error.Please check my updated post.

Comment: did you try echo $json; instead of print_r($json);

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this first:

```
console.log(data);
```

If this provides a valid string format, then your `JSON.parse(data)` will work. But it's quite evident that that is not the case here.

For e.g. `JSON.parse('{"1": 1, "2": 2}')` would work but not `JSON.parse({"1": 1, "2": 2})`

Comment: console message is not executing at all.before that this error is coming.

Comment: What happens if you comment out this line `console.log('add data',data,JSON.parse(data));`

Comment: actually this type ` $arr = array('msg' => "Data Deleted Successfully!!!", 'error' => '');` message giving that error.while i wrote `echo $data_id  ` its coming properly.